# PHP basics - $_POST

Tags: php

I'm started to learn PHP only some weeks ago, and I have a problem with posting a value from form.
Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);?>" 
method="POST">
            <input type="text" name="name">
            <br/>
            <input type="submit">
        </form>
        <?php 
            echo $_POST['name'];
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

[image]
[image]

It displays an error
But when I try to write something in the input field, it is working perfectly

Comment: Note `action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);?>"` is completely unncesessary almost always, if you just don't include the `action=` part at all, it will by default post back to the same page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because before you post the form you're trying to print `$_POST['name']` *which doesn't exist yet*. If you make a check before printing it it should remove the warning

```
if (isset($_POST['name'])) {
    echo $_POST['name'];
}
```